# ClosedXML.Excel.XLCell Verify if Cell have Bold Properties

Tags: c#, closedxml

Hi i have a XLCell and need to validate if that cell have Bold style.

```
 IXLCell cell = worksheet.Cell(12, 5);
            if (cell.Style.Font.Bold)
            {
                callFunction();
            }
```

Open xlsx the cell have the Bold style active.
Using c# and closedXml how can i validate if cell have bold style active? Should be with other properties or styles?

Thks in advance

Answer (score 1):

cell.Style.Font.Bold is a property with both a get and a set method so you should be able to do the following:

```
IXLCell = worksheet.Cell(12, 5);
if (cell.Style.Font.Bold == true)
{
    callFunction();
}
```

Check out the [ClosedXML Documentation](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml/wiki) for more details.